# Find documents with matching the field's object value

Tags: mongodb, laravel, connection, jenssegers-mongodb

My mongodb table has a field which has object value like

```
_id : ObjectId("59ad227e191cc3a4c33ade07")
user_info : {"first_name": "Shraddha", "last_name": "Banerjee", "Zip": "90242", "City": "SantaBarbara"}
```

I want to find the users with Zip: 90242.

I tried doing it like:

```
$users = User::where('user_info.Zip','=', 90242)->get();
```

But this gives me empty result.
How can this be achieved ?

Comment: First take `$info = $user_info['Zip'];` and then use `$users = User::where($info,'=', 90242)->get();` Let me know if this works!

Comment: Have you tried it??

Comment: Hi @Hiren, It doesn't work. Its an object stored inside user_info. It gives error : Undefined variable: user_info. Well i also tried using 
$info = "user_info.Zip";
$users = User::where($info,'=', 90242)->get();

Comment: `$user_info` i said, you need to take your variable where json object comes from!

Comment: I just have the Zip coming from my POST request. This JSON is the stored document in my mongoDB collection. This I have achieved doing in MySQL like this :
$users   =   User::where('user_info->Zip', $zip)
                                    ->where('user_info->DateOfBirth', 'like', '%'.$date_of_year.'%')
                                    ->get(['user_info', 'user_id']); 

But using mongo cannot fetch it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that your zip data is stored string and when you query it you are using integer.

```
$users = User::where('user_info.Zip','=', '90242')->get();
```

try to cast zip to string when you do the query

Answer (score 1):

try this instead,

```
$users = User::where('user_info.Zip', '90242')->get();
```